# fullCalendar custom events function throws not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

im feeding the calendar with the following function:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        events: function(callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/appointments.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                        events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                        });
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
object is not a function //callback(events) line
```

On the js console of the browser. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: events: '/appointments.json' works just fine. The problem is in the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using FullCalendar 2.*, as stated in the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/), the signature for `events` is

> function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }

The parameter with the name `callback` is, in fact, `start` which is a `momentjs` object. To resolve your issue you must add the parameters to your function, so your code would be:

```
events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
```

This will work as long as your `events` (passed to the `callback`) have the correct format and parameters defined in the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

Edit:

If you want to set background color of each event according to a value on its json attributes, you should use [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/). 
Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/666uvdcj) where the background of each event is set when the event is rendering.

As is demonstrated in the jsfiddle, you can change the background, conditionally, based on a value provided by the json.

Comment: thanks @milz, but im still getting the same error. Sorry i Cant edit my question again, now my function is the same but with the parameters you mentioned: function( start, end, timezone, callback )

Comment: Please see the [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/6ssmuzo7/). I am assuming the format of the `doc` and I didn't use `$.ajax` to simplify. If you guarantee that `doc` has the same format, it must work. Also check FullCalendar's version. I'm using 2.1.1

Comment: thanks @milz but still the same, even if i copy paste all your code. Maybe im missing something on fullCalendar library.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the libs that you are using and the `doc` format? It seems that the issue is related to the libraries your using or some confict with them... Try changing the name `calback` to `somethingelse` (both in the params and the call) and see if it works.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to convert a javascript object into a jQuery selector. `$(doc)` will instantly give you an error and the following code won't work either. I must ask, Is there a good reason to use events as a function instead of `events: '/appointments.json'`.

Comment: Well, the reason is i want to set the background color of each event according to a value on its json attributes..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63047/discussion-between-milz-and-ntonnelier).

Comment: What is solution for full calendar version - 4? Thanks.